# Build Jenkins project on BitBucket pushes and pull requests

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks, bitbucket-api

I have a scenario where I'm setting up Jenkins for my app. I have BitBucket set up and firing appropriate webhooks. 
I want to start a build whenever a push is made to the repo as well as whenever someone creates/updates a pull request.
I've looked at the [BitBucket Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin). It works good if I have the BitBucket webhook to fire for all pushes.
Then I added the [BitBucket Pull request plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+pullrequest+builder+plugin) to build on every pull request create/update. So I changed the BitBucket webhook preferences to fire on pushes and PR creates/updates.

Unfortunately, these plugins have conflicting settings, hence they cannot be used at the same time (as per my research, the minute I send custom webhooks from BitBucket, the first one stops working, but the second one works)

Has anyone been able to set this up correctly? Maybe there's a plugin for what I want, but I couldn't find it.

I want to keep writing a proxy in front of Jenkins to manage webhooks the last option, only if there really is nothing I can do.

Thanks for the help!